# variable stays empty in SH script

Tags: shell, sh

The banner grab using curl to variable seems to sty empty.
when i remove the > /dev/null /dev/null 2>&1 the output is written to screen but i need it in var BANNER without screen, what am i doing wrong?

```sh
 IPS="$(< scandata.dat)"        

 for IP in $IPS;                
 do                             
        TRY1="$(curl -m 2 -s -o /dev/null --head -w "%{http_code}" -X POST "rtsp://$IP:554")"  
        if [ "$TRY1" -eq 200 ]              
                then                                                                                                                                                    
                    BANNER=$(curl -m 2 -v -s rtsp://$IP:554 > /dev/null 2>&1 )  #Error    
                    echo $BANNER &>> FullBanners.txt
        fi
                    if [[ "$BANNER" == *"TEXT"* ]]; then
                        echo $IP &>> TEXT.txt
                    fi          
done
```

Comment: You've got some syntax issues here -- f/e, `[` will always fail unless its last argument is `]`.

Comment: Also, more generally, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...and all-caps variable names are reserved for variables that change shell or standard-utility behavior -- it's safer to use names with at least one lowercase character for your own variables (like how `for path in "$dir"/*; do` is safe, but `for PATH in "$dir"/*; do` will prevent your shell from being able to run any external commands). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Comment: Also, this definitely isn't a `sh` script. `&>>` isn't valid in baseline sh, for example, at least, if you mean the `&` to imply that stderr should also be redirected -- that's an extension only supported by newer shells. `[[` also isn't a `sh` feature.

Comment: Coming back to your real question, though... in `> /dev/null /dev/null 2>&1`, what do you expect that second `/dev/null` to actually _do_? The real meaning is exactly the same as `/dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` -- meaning, you have one `/dev/null` as an argument to the copy of `curl`, and a second `/dev/null` used as a redirection target.

Comment: i shredded the  real code to make it more readable. i made some errors [ "$TRY1" -eq 200  ]  and BANNER=$(curl -m 2 -v -s rtsp://$IP:554 > /dev/null /dev/null 2>&1 )

Comment: @Dentricky73 That's fine, but obviously then you should run, post, and ask about the behavior of your shredded code

Comment: (`$(<filename)` is another thing this code is doing that's guaranteed to work in bash but not in `sh`)

Comment: Very strange the var $TRY1 works without any problems
i tried the same

BANNER="$(curl -m 2 -v -s -o /dev/null "rtsp://$IP:554" > /dev/null 2>&1 )"

without luck

Comment: remove `> /dev/null` and `-o /dev/null`. Keep `2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

i have no clue what i did, but changing

```sh
BANNER=$(curl -m 2 -v -s rtsp://$IP:554 > /dev/null 2>&1 )
```

to

```sh
BANNER="$(curl -m 2 -s -o /dev/null --head -w  -X POST "rtsp://$IP:554")"
```

did the job for me.
This must be an ugly hack, at least it works(for me)

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

says:

First, throw away stdout.

Then, redirect stderr to where stdout is right now. Since stdout goes to /dev/null due to the first redirection, stderr goes to /dev/null as well.

Therefore your variable stays empty.

You should have done a

```
2>&1 >/dev/null
```

instead.